# Where can I find whether or not an aircraft requires two pilots?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations

I am trying to build custom scenarios for myself and I wanted to know where is an exact place for me to look If an aircraft needs two pilots.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the minimum crew required in the aircraft Type Certificate Data Sheet (TCDS).  It is available from this FAA [link](https://drs.faa.gov/browse/TCDSMODEL/doctypeDetails) (the FAA's Dynamic Regulatory System - DRS).

Note: In the *search criteria field* (in the DRS) when you enter the aircraft you're interested in, just use the model number.  For example, for a Boeing 737 you would type in **737**, **not B737**, for a **Learjet 24** you would type in **24**, etc.

Here is a TCDS example/excerpt from the FAA's Dynamic Regulatory System for the **737**:

[image]

(*emphasis is mine*)

Also, there are certain types of operations where a single-pilot certificated aircraft requires two pilots.  For example, under FAR Part 135, a Cessna 172 (type certificated requiring a single pilot), operating under IFR and not equipped with an approved autopilot (the use of which is authorized by operations specifications),  requires a second-in-command when carrying passengers - ([Source 1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-135.101) and ([Source 2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-135.105).